# Binding Data from A Dataset to a <asp:Table>

Tags: asp.net, t-sql

Here I got slapped by a nice Surprise! `<asp:Table>` has no DataSource property. So far I have this code.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Careers"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Careers", conn);
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(comm);
System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
System.Data.DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
//tbVCareers.IMAGINARYDATASOURCE = dt;
tbVCareers.DataBind();
```

This is only a testpage I am writing , so the Table is not supposed to look pretty. How am I to bind Data to this table? Note, this is not the same database connection that I posted in an earlier question. Any insight someone can Lend to me?

Comment: why dont you use <asp:GridView>??

Comment: I had a slow moment :/ all fixed now ^_^ Sorry, I am still new to asp.net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<asp:Table>` is  not data control, so you cannot do that with `<asp:Table>`. you have to use `<asp:GridView>`

Comment: thats the ticket. thanks a lot! wow , i feel like an idiot now XD

Comment: So is <asp:Table> the equivalent of HTML's <Table> ?

Comment: Its a server control that renders an HTML table.